# Tablet as a secondary monitor

Tags: samsung, tablet, secondary-display

Do I have any option to use my Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (2014 edition) as a secondary screen?

I want to use it for Photoshop, which runs on the PC, but I control it on the tablet. I know I can draw with the tab, and there are apps for drawing, and I've already used Sketchbook (Autodesk) but it has a lot of limits with the layers and brushes.

I have already tried applications like "Splashtop" via the internet but it was very laggy, and I also gave a chance to "Slide" (because of the USB connection) but the installation didn't work.

I don't really trust apps which work via the internet because it might be very slow and laggy, and it's a big deal in computer drawing, so I look for a solution which works via HDMI or USB cable.

Does anyone have an idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

- [Air Display by Avatron](http://avatron.com/applications/air-display/)
- [iDisplay](http://www.getidisplay.com/)
- [Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/downloads#pers_sec)